# Oracle Pattern matching

Tags: oracle

In Oracle I want to check whether the string has "=' sign at the end. could you please let me know how to check it. If it has '=' sign at the end of string, I need to trailing that '=' sign.

for eg,

```
varStr VARCHAR2(20);

varStr = 'abcdef='; --needs to trailing '=' sign
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `REGEX_EXP` function. I'm putting a sql command since you didn't specify on your question.:

```
select * 
  from someTable
 where regexp_like( someField, '=$' );
```

The pattern `$` means that the precedent character should be at the end of the string.

see it here on sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8afd/3

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need "pattern matching" here. Just check if the last character is the `=`

```
where substr(varstr, -1, 1) = '='
```

`substr` when called with a negative position will work from the end of the string, so `substr(varstr,-1,1)` extracts the last character of the given string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that substr is the way to go, at lease with my sample data of about 400K address lines this returns 1043 entries that end in 'r' in an average of 0.2 seconds.

```
select count(*) from addrline where substr(text, -1, 1) = 'r';
```

On the other hand, the following returns the same results but takes 1.1 seconds.

```
select count(*) from addrline where regexp_like(text, 'r$' );
```